# How to read Arc/Info e00 vector files (no binaries) with Python?

Tags: python, e00

I can easily read e00 files with QGIS and it seems as if in older versions of ogr there was driver support for the arc/info e00 file format. Nowadays that seems to be deprecated, as running `ogrinfo --formats` doesn't list arc/info.

I also found this useful [link](http://avce00.maptools.org/docs/v7_e00_cover.html), a general description of the file format. Based on that information I would be able to write my own program to put all the pieces together. But hey, this must have been done before, right?

Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Comment: It shouldn't be deprecated in OGR, accoding to [this page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html) it should be one of the default drivers. What distribution/version of GDAL are you using?

Comment: I've seen this page. But it does not refer to the python ogr bindings as far as I can see.

Comment: You should have the same drivers available to the python bindings as listed from ogrinfo (python bindings are just a wrapper around the c/c++ library that ogrinfo uses itself). The only exception to that would be plugin drivers, which require environment variables to be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness sake.

```
acr_file = r'../xxx.e00' 
dr = ogr.GetDriverByName("AVCE00")
f = dr.Open(arc_file)
```

In my case, if I do a layer count I will get 2 because the e00-file contains polylines and -points.

```
f.GetLayerCount()
>>> 2
```

Lines are always named 'ARC', whereas points are named 'LAB'. So

```
lyr_arc = f.GetLayerByName('ARC')
lyr_arc.GetFeatureCount()
>>> 476562
```

will give you access to the polylines part and

```
lyr_lab = f.GetLayerByName('LAB')
lyr_lab.GetFeatureCount()
>>> 62882
```

to the points part of the file.

Comment: Nice. Mark as answered?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ArcGIS installed then you can run the conversion program in the bin directory. On my machine it is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin\import71.exe`

I've not tried it, but may be you can call it from the command prompt with parameters?

Comment: No arcgis. Also i need a python approach, as stated in my question.

Comment: I was thinking you would spawning a shell process in Python but as you do not have ArcGIS this won't work.